# QWidget winId crashing if called from constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program, where i call`QWidget::winId()`in the constructor:

```
debug_window::debug_window(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::debug_window),
    hk(NULL)
{
    this->ui->setupUi(this);
    this->hk = new TestClass(this, this->winId())
}
```

But this will cause my program to crash, even before a window is created. I already figured out that the call of winId causes the crash, probably because at this time there is no window existing. (correct me if I'm wrong).
Sadly, there is no signal "windowCreated()" or something similar. So is there any way to find out that the window was created, or how to in general solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `winId` may not exists before your window will be shown. And it may be changed in some cases (for example: dockable windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create signal and emit him in the end of constructor.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect! Sometimes I just think to complicated ;)